# value is undefined untill response comes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside a controller, there is a function that sends $http request to the server and when it gets the response, it assigns that response to, let's say. $scope.number!

I show that $scope.number in the html page:

```
<p ng-bind="number"></p>
```

The problem is that, unit I get the response from the server, it shows 'undefined' in the browser.

How can I give default value to this? I mean, how can I show 0 until the response comes?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, but I tried to simplify the case, but I think I gave a bad example.

Actually, the request gets an object: $scope.group! This object contains a list of students. And my html looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="student in group">
    <p ng-bind="student.average_progress"></p>
</div>
```

This is showing 'undefined' and initializing it like this:

```
$scope.group.student.average_progress = 0
```

is not helping

Comment: so at initial state you have some values in group variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:-

```
<p ng-bind="number=number || 0"></p>
```

Comment: <p ng-bind="student.average_progress=student.average_progress|| 0"></p>

Comment: of course, why did I not think of it myself?) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think setting `$scope.number = 0` before the `$http` request will work.

Answer (score 0):

in the controller, initialize the variable $scope.number = 0, before invoking the service, and when the response is received from the server, reassign the value of $scope.number to the value from the server. so the value will be zero until the response is received from the server

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-show="number" on the same tag, also ng-init="number=default"

Answer (score 0):

Set `$scope.number = 0` in controller definition. 
It should be something like:

```
.controller('MyController', function() { 
$scope.number = 0; 
(...)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the value to 0 before calling $http

```
$scope.number = 0
```